# How to automate kendo ui dropdown using webdriver/ java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to kendo and selenium webdriver, I just need to automate the kendo `ui drop down list`, I am able to list the drop down option but I'm not able to select the value. If I tried to select the value am getting an error. I have listed the code used to identify the value

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.k-input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.k-item.k-state-selected.k-state-focused")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not share your html code so see below general answer to solve your issue.

Please check following :

**Syntax :**

```
   //SELECT SPECIFIC VALUE FROM DROPDOWN
   Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("yourdropdownid")));
   sel.selectByVisibleText("valueofdropdownoption");
```

**Example :**

```
   //SELECT SPECIFIC VALUE FROM DROPDOWN
   Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("continents")));
   sel.selectByVisibleText("Australia");
```

Note : you can use any like id , css selector ,xpath , class to find element.

Also I would like to point you to kendo ui demo using web driver :

```
 driver.get("http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/index.html");

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='options']/span[1]/span/span[1]")).click();

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='color_listbox']/li[2]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply...this will work for normal html dropdown list and am using kendo ui...i tried this code but not able to succeed.... this is the html tag declared for the dropdown        <span class="k-input" unselectable="on">adas</span>

Comment: Hi sir, i just gone through your code..during playback itz enabling the drop down but not selecting the value"orange" from the list..is there any other way to do it??  **drop down is same as in the provided url**

Comment: Using Xpath it is working there , see my updated code.

Comment: Am getting error like this how to resolve it:                                                   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 35 milliseconds

Comment: please use wait before element.

Comment: can you please explain it with eg;;; i have user  :         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  but still getting the error

Comment: still the error exist as  fallow :     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='ddlschedule_listbox']/li[3]

Comment: please share your web driver code by update question.

Comment: hi helping hands thanks for you support, i made it by using thread.sleep(15000)..;)